# Room description in room card can have illegal unicode characters from truncation

Tags: bug, chat, unicode

[image: screenshot of Java chatroom on chat.SO's room card]

You can see the room card on the right [in the transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/139).

Notice how the last character is displayed as a replacement character, which is wrong.

Comment: Yet another unicode bug.